# PHP: Undefined index

Tags: php, oop, web

I have probably made a very simple mistake with this, but I do not see how.. If any of you could help me, I would appreciate it lots.

This is my error:
`Notice: Undefined index: admin in C:\xampp\htdocs\forums\classes\User.php on line 75`

Here is User.php

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

    if ($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        if ($permissions[$key] == true) { <<< This is line 75 <<<
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is where I use hasPermission()

```
if($user->hasPermission("admin")){
    echo "You are an administrator";
}
```

`var_dump($key);`:

```
string(5) "admin"
```

`var_dump($permissions);`

```
array(1) { ["admin"]=> int(1) }
```

`var_dump($permissions[$key]);` outputs:

```
NULL
```

Comment: `var_dump($key);` before `if ($permissions[$key] == true)` and see what it outputs.

Comment: array(1) { ["admin"]=> int(1) }

Comment: Could you try `if ((bool)$permissions[$key] == true)` if it suits your needs?

Comment: @TheDeadLike Still erroring Undefined Index

Comment: @AmalMurali, returns null..

Comment: var_dump($permissions) and put the result in your question

Comment: Can you check if(array_key_exists($key,$permissions)){ echo "exists" ;} else { echo "not exists" ;} inside the function ?

Comment: @AwladLiton I have already done that, check above.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Not exists

Comment: Meaning the returned data from DB might be having a white space. You may use trim() to remove that. You can additionally check 
if(array_key_exists("admin",$permissions)){ echo "exists" ;} else { echo "not exists" ;}
If the above returns exists then DB returned data is ok, you need to trim() the $key, else you need to trim() the DB returned Data

Comment: What does your `json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);` function and what is it's full expected return?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, Broken solved the issue.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty If an empty space were to return, wouldn't that dump into string(1) " " though? OP's `$permissions` output was `int(1)` inside `["admin"]`. Meanwhile however, that didn't still explain how did the key output `NULL` instead, or am I the one missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this one:

```
if (isset($permissions[$key]) && $permissions[$key] == 1) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: If there's a bug, you should fix it, not hide it. Working around using `isset()` might work now, but just keep in mind that hidden bugs often come back to bite you.